# On the number of integer points with even coordinates in the interior of a lattice triangle

Tags: combinatorics, triangles, integer-lattices

I am looking at triangles with vertices $(0,1)$, $(0,2k+1)$, $(2l+1, 2k+1)$ where $k$ and $l$ are integers and $2l$ and $2k+1$ are prime to each other. I am trying to describe $P\pmod2$, where $P$ the number of integer points $(x,y)$ with $x\equiv 0 \pmod2$ and $y \equiv 0 \pmod2$ lying in the interior of such triangles.
For $k=1$ or $k=2$, it is easy to work out a formula for $P$, and in general it looks like the behaviour of $P$ depends only on $l$ and $k \pmod{2l}$. Do you know any result or trick that could help me with this problem ?

Comment: It's easy to compute the number of integer points in the interior of the rectangle with vertices $(0,1)$, $(0,2k+1)$, $(2l+1,1)$, and $(2l+1,2k+1)$. I think the coprime condition you've imposed implies that there are no integer points on the diagonal from $(0,1)$, so that $P$ is just one half of that number.

Comment: @rogerl That is not true anymore when you only want to count integer points of a given parity (which is the case here). For example, for $l=k=1$, the rectangle with vertices $(0,1)$, $(0,3)$, $(3,3)$ and $(3,1)$ contains only one point whose coordinates are both congruent to $0$ $($ mod 2 $)$. This point is not on the diagonal of the rectangle (as you mentionned, that's what the coprime condition ensures), so it has to lie either above or below this diagonal.